# maps from infinite sets to infinite sets

Tags: functions

I know that the set of irrationals is uncountable, but I feel that there can always a bijection from one infinite set to a subset of another infinite set. Does this sound right? Say, from Irrationals to a subset of Rationals.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible. Cantor showed first that such a bijection DOES not exists using his famous diagonal argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. For example, an uncountable set can't inject into (a subset of) a countable set by definition of 'countable', so it certainly can't biject with it.

Answer (score 1):

The infinite sets form a hierarchy. Just like the finite sets. Consider two finite sets $n$ and $m$, one will be bijective with a subset of the other, like say $7$ and $9$, $7$ is bijective with a subset of $9$, but not the otherway around, $9$ is not bijective with a subset of $7$. The same with infinite sets, the rationals are bijective with a subset of the irrationals but not the otherway around the irrationals are not bijective with a subset of the rationals. The infinity of the irrationals is higher in the hierarchy than the rationals.